# Django - cascade on other condition

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm using Django and a Postgres database and I have two tables (Authors, Books).

I don't want to enable to deletion of any records, instead to change the boolean of an unseen field called 'active' - a field both tables have. What i'd like to happen is when a user changes an Author's 'active' field to False, all of the books with a FK to this author in the Books table have their 'active' field's also set to False.

In Django, my only options it seems related to deletion, how would I set this up with the models.py file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this with [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#signals). In the following example I assume your `Book` model has a foreign key field that looks like this.

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    ...
    author = models.ForeignKey("Author", related_name="books")
    ...
```

### Option 1. Use Signals

An example function hooked into the `Author` `post_save` signal.

```py
from django.db import transaction
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

def update_books_status(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    with transaction.atomic():
        books = Books.objects.select_for_update().filter(author=instance)
        for book in books:
            book.active = False
            book.save()


post_save.connect(update_books_status, sender=Author)
```

In this example the atomic [transaction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/transactions/) ensures that all the updates are run in a single DB query. This saves you from the `n+1` issue you would have if you just ran through the query set in a `for` loop.

### Option 2. Override `save()`

Another way to handle this that is probably better is to override the `Author` model `save()` method.

```py
class Author(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Make sure we are not saving a new Author
        # And we are saving the Author as inactive
        # And we are are saving an Author that was active.
        if not self._state.adding and not self.active and self._loaded_values['active']:
            self.inactivate_books()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def inactivate_books(self):
        with transaction.atomic():
            books = Books.objects.select_for_update().filter(author=self)
            for book in books:
                book.active = False
                book.save()
```

Comment: great answer, helps a lot